# Could Columbus have suspected the New World lay on his path to India?

Tags: india, 15th-century, new-world, exploration, travel

According to most historical textbooks Columbus made mistakes while measuring the size of the Earth. This led him to believe, that he can travel to India westwards in a reasonable time. This is however quite strange, that he let no one correct him in his mistake.

Could it be possible and was it ever considered by the historians, that Columbus was simply lying that he can find the way to India? That he knew about existence of Americas somehow and used the lie to get funding for his operation?

Comment: Vote to close; unless there is some evidence, this is counterfactual pseudoscience.  Is there a possibility that Columbus lied? Yes.  But if you assume that he knew about the existence of the America's and rather than publishing his knowledge he conspired to take a risky ocean voyage, then you enter the realm of pseudohistory.

Comment: This question might be on-topic at Skeptics.SE.

Comment: In order to make it possible, one of three things would have to happen. Columbus being a time traveler, having close encounter with representatives of some alien form of life or having a vision from God himself. This way either the reliable sources on that matter 1) weren't written yet, as the case will start in the future, 2) are kept in some kind of Galactic Library, written in the language most probably not available for us 3) need to be taken at faith, or are kept in Vatican, which would be the easiest, especially that there's an American resident recently.

Comment: This is actually an interesting question, that needs better phrasing - "Could Columbus have suspected the New World lay on his path to India?" The answer is, actually, "Maybe, but probably not" and involves a survey of Renaissance Italy, Basque, Irish, Scandanavian and African culture, and how well they cross-polinated, if at all.

Comment: I edited the title, according to @RISwampYankee 's suggestion and also edited the keywords a bit. I think the question can be opened with the new neutral title.

Comment: I'm sympathetic to re-opening, but not without evidence. Otherwise it is random speculation.   Why is it implausible that Columbus made an error?

Comment: Again, recommended for Skeptics.SE

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any way that this question could be answered without speculating. I agree that it would be a better fit for Skeptics.SE.

Comment: It is not unplausible that he made an error. It is unplausible that he didn't have it corrected.

Comment: To reopen this question, I suggest that the following information be added: (1) Someone in ancient Greece calculated the circumference of the earth to within, I don't quite remember, ten percent accuracy; (2) this information was known in 15th-century Spain; (3) How did Columbus expect to travel so far with limited provisions; (4) How did he react to the much sooner than expected landfall. At least (1) and (2) must be added.

Comment: The question "could he have suspected" is a resounding "yes". He *could*. He probably didn't. But that's a pretty silly question. The question also seems to really be "was he lying" which of course in not answerable. Voting to keep closed.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel 10% for such a thing is **a lot**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a valid question. But the answer is a rather resounding no. For one thing, we have no shred of evidence for such a conjecture. For another, this conjecture cannot be squared at all with the fact that Columbus to his dying day insisted on having actually landed in India - had he been dissimulating about his knowledge of the existence of America, surely after he got there he could have come clean.

The actual story how the great voyage was conceived is told with great detail (not all of it savoury) by Lord Acton in chapter 2 of his [lectures on modern history](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/18685/pg18685.txt).